# Reading files and displaying their content

Tags: java, reinventing-the-wheel, error-handling

I'm writing a program to read two files supplied as arguments in the command line, convert them from list to char[][], and display their contents to the user.

I'm trying to practice exception-handling and javadocs, so I'm not interested in using a library. Also, this will be part of a larger program, hence the conversions happening, but I just want to focus on the I/O part for now. All comments are welcome!

```
public class Utilities {
    /**
     * This class must not be instantiated.
     */

    private Utilities() {}

    /**
     * Reads a file and returns a <code>List<String></code>.
     *
     * @param file path to the file
     * @return a <code>List<String></code> containing every line from the file
     * @throws AccessDeniedException if access rights are insufficient
     * @throws EOFException if the file is empty
     * @throws IOException I/O exception
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException (unchecked) if the path string cannot be converted
     *         to a <code>Path</code>
     * @throws NoRegularFileException if the file is not a regular file
     * @throws NoSuchFileException if the file does not exist
     * @throws SecurityException (unchecked) In the case of the default provider,
     *         and a security manager is installed, the <code>checkRead</code> is invoked
     *         to check read access to the file.
     */

    public static List<String> readFile(String file)
            throws NoSuchFileException, EOFException, IOException {
        Path p = Paths.get(file);
        if (!Files.exists(p)) {
            throw new NoSuchFileException(file);
        } else if (!Files.isRegularFile(p)) {
            throw new NoRegularFileException(file);
        } else if (!Files.isReadable(p)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedException(file);
        } else if (Files.size(p) == 0) {
            throw new EOFException(file);
        }
        return Files.readAllLines(p);
    }

    /**
      * Converts a <code>List</code> of any type to a <code>char[][]</code>.
      * 
      * @param <T> the type of the element
      * @param l a <code>List</code>
      * @return a <code>char[][]</code>. If the <code>List</code> is <code>null</code>,
      *         returns <code>null</code>. If an element of the <code>List</code> is
      *         <code>null</code>, the corresponding array is set to <code>null</code>.
      */

     public static <T> char[][] listToCharArray(List<T> l) {
         if (l == null) {
             return null;
         }

         char[][] arr = new char[l.size()][];
         {
             int i = 0;
             for (T t : l) {
                 if (t == null) {
                     arr[i++] = null;
                 } else {
                     arr[i++] = t.toString().toCharArray();
                 }
             }
          }
          return arr;
      }

      /**
       * Displays a <code>char[][]</code>.
       *
       * @param arr a <code>char[][]</code>
       */

      public static void display(char[][] arr) {
          for (char[] line : arr) {
              for (char c : line) {
                  System.out.print(c);
              }
              System.out.println();
          }
      }
  }

  class NoRegularFileException extends FileSystemException {
      public NoRegularFileException(String file) {
          super(file);
      }
  }

public class MyProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.err.println("The proper use is: java MyProgram file1.txt file2.txt");
                return;
            }

            List<List<String>> files = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String s : args) {
                try {
                    files.add(Utilities.readFile(s));
                } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
                    System.err.printf("File %s does not exist%n", e.getMessage());
                    return;
                } catch (NoRegularFileException e) {
                    System.err.printf("File %s is not a regular file%n", e.getMessage());
                    return;
                } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
                    System.err.printf(
                "Access rights are insufficient to read file %s%n", e.getMessage()
                    );
                    return;
                } catch (EOFException e) {
                    System.err.printf("File %s is empty%n", e.getMessage());
                    return;
                }
             }

             char[][] file1 = Utilities.listToCharArray(files.get(0));
             char[][] file2 = Utilities.listToCharArray(files.get(1));
             Utilities.display(file1);
             Utilities.display(file2);
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.err.printf("Error: %s%n", e.getMessage());
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Why are you converting the files which are List<String> into char[][]? You could just println all Strings in a list.

Comment: @Traubenfuchs Later in my program, the char[][] will be more convenient to use than a List<String> so I'll be printing from the char[][].

Comment: What is `NoRegularFileException`? I can't find that class in the Java API.

Comment: @Tunaki sorry I forgot to include it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's been a while since I asked this question and I've improved this part of the code, so I'm posting it as an answer.

Edit: To answer rolfl's concerns, the main improvement to the first version of the code is the removal of the wrapper function around Files.readAllLines.

It felt redundant since it is already a wrapper around the verbose way of reading files and it is just two lines of code. Also, the point of that wrapper function was to throw more specific exceptions, but I later found out that Files.readAllLines already throws these exceptions, even though it is not specified in the documentation.

In the end, the result is a more straightforward code, where exception handling is simpler and exceptions are caught closer to the point they can be dealt with.

```
package project;

/**
 * This class consists exclusively of static utility methods.
 */
final class Utilities {
    /**
     * This class must not be instantiated.
     */
    private Utilities() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This class must not be instantiated");
    }

    /**
     * Converts a list of any type to a two-dimensional (2D) {@code char}
     * array.
     * 
     * <p>The 2D array will contain all of the elements in the list as internal
     * arrays, in proper sequence from first to last element. If an element
     * of the list is {@code null}, the corresponding internal array is set to
     * {@code null}.
     * 
     * <p>The elements are converted to strings by
     * {@link java.lang.Object#toString() toString()} internally, so the method
     * should be properly overridden.
     * 
     * @param   <T>
     *          the type of the element
     * @param   l
     *          a list to be converted
     * @return  a {@code char[][]} containing the elements of the list. If
     *          {@code l} is {@code null}, returns {@code null}.
     * @see     java.util.ArrayList#toArray()
     */
    private static <T> char[][] listToCharArray(List<T> l) {
        if (l == null) {
            return null;
        }

        char[][] arr = new char[l.size()][];
        {
            int i = 0;
            for (T t : l) {
                if (t == null) {
                    arr[i++] = null;
                } else {
                    arr[i++] = t.toString().toCharArray();
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }

    /**
     * Displays a <code>char[][]</code>.
     *
     * @param arr a <code>char[][]</code>
     */
    public static void display(char[][] arr) {
        for (char[] line : arr) {
            for (char c : line) {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

package project;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

final class MyProgram {
    /**
     * This class must not be instantiated.
     */
    private MyProgram() {
        throw new IllegalStateException("This class must not be instantiated");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != Config.NUMBER_OF_FILES) {
            System.err.println(
                "The proper use is: java MyProgram file1 file2"
            );
            return;
        }

        List<List<String>> files = new ArrayList<>(args.length);
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            try {
                Path p = Paths.get(args[i]);
                files.add(Files.readAllLines(p));
                if (files.get(i).isEmpty()) {
                    System.err.printf("File %1s is empty%n", args[i]);
                    return;
                }
            } catch (NoSuchFileException e) {
                System.err.printf("File %1s does not exist%n", e.getMessage());
                return;
            } catch (AccessDeniedException e) {
                System.err.printf(
                    "Access rights are insufficient to read file %1s%n",
                    e.getMessage()
                );
                return;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.printf(
                    "An error occurred while reading file %1s%n",
                    args[i]
                );
                return;
            }
        }
        char[][] file1 = Utilities.listToCharArray(files.get(0));
        char[][] file2 = Utilities.listToCharArray(files.get(1));
        Utilities.display(file1);
        Utilities.display(file2);         
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice self-answer.